# Double click in date field should display the current date

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have 2 items `:P1_START_DATE` and `:P1_END_DATE`.

I need to display the current date in these two field when I double click the items, I need this through dynamic action.

Thanks!
Abinnaya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Dynamic Action that triggers on `Event: Double Click`, `Selection Type: Item(s)`, and `Item(s): :P1_START_DATE` for each of your items.

Then your `True Action` should be `Execute JavaScript` with the code like this:

```
var myDate = new Date();
var dd = String(myDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(myDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
var yyyy = myDate.getFullYear();

// Here you can format your date the way you want it to look.
myDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

apex.item("P1_START_DATE").setValue(myDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you know how to create a dynamic action you can use:

```
Set Value

Setting -> PL/SQL Function Body

begin
    return to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'); -- or your format mask
end;

Affected Items: P1_START_DATE, P1_END_DATE
```

I try to avoid JavaScript where possible.